Gradle build failing, possibly because of incompatible Java and Gradle versions
I have developed 2 apps for personal use. I do this as a hobby and find the interaction between Android Studio, Java and Gradle very confusing.
When I opened Android Studio for the first time in months to make a minor modification to one app I followed a prompt to upgrade Android Studio to Iguana 2023.2.1 . After doing that the Gradle build for one of the apps failed. In attempting to resolve this I followed a suggestion to use "AGP Upgrade Assistant" to upgrade from 4.0.1 to 4.2.2. The Gradle build now fails with following messages:

Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script
'C:\Users\prepb\AppData\Local\Temp\ijWrapper1.gradle'
(C:\Users\prepb.gradle\caches\6.7.1\scripts\pyh0v03oa5pxvesmcpjvakm7).

BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 61


Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.


I've seen this thread BUG! Exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version where the poster was advised to check that Java and Gradle versions are compatible.
The accepted solution includes a screenshot for a window where the "Gradle JDK" can be found at Preferences → Build,Execution,Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle. I can't find Preferences in the menus. Where can I find this information in Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2 (Windows 10)?

The answer to my question is that Settings are under the File menu (in the Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1 on Windows 10).
In File>Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Build Tools>Gradle the "Gradle JDK" was set to "JAVA_HOME JetBrains Runtime version 17.0.9".
The Gradle version (shown in File>Project structure) is 6.7.1
The table in BUG! Exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version shows that for that version of Gradle the Java version has to be 14 or less.
The "Gradle JDK" dropdown has a link to "Download JDK …". I used this to download JDK version 11.0.23.
After that the Gradle Build succeeded.

“Preferences” may be “Settings” on some host OSes.

Thanks, but I can't see Settings either.

Edit your Question to state your OS.

Read The Fine Manual: https://www.jetbrains.com/guide/java/tutorials/configuring-intellij-idea/configuring-preferences-settings/

Someone has marked the question "-1". I am an inexperienced programmer looking for friendly help.. What have I done wrong?

Thanks, Basil. That jetbrains page helped me to find Settings under the File menu. (I get flustered whenever anything goes wrong in Android Studio, and in my panic I must have failed to see it when I looked earlier.)  In Settings → Build,Execution,Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle I found the option to "Download JDK ..." I have downloaded JDK 11 to replace 17 and after that the Gradle Build is successful. Thanks again.
